# How to change tab indicator color and text color while swiping tab using ViewPager?

Tags: android

This is my code. How to add tabindicator color and text color in this java class?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        actionBar  = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);  // hides action bar icon
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // hides action bar title

        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

     mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_menu, null);

        i = (ImageButton)mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    e = (EditText)mCustomView. findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    e.setVisibility(mCustomView.INVISIBLE);



        TabAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);


        Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                        actionBar = getActionBar();
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position); 
                        }
                });


        Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
     //   Tab.showContextMenu();
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
      actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

                // set background for action bar tab
        actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")));       

        actionBar.show();

        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                    FragmentTransaction ft) {

            }

            @Override
             public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {  
                Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());





            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                    FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }};
            //Add New Tab
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("SPOTLIGHT").setTabListener(tabListener));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("WHAT'S NEW").setTabListener(tabListener));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("HOT ITEMS").setTabListener(tabListener));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a tab layout where each tab has a custom textView and add that tab in the tablayout with whatever color of your choice

```
View customView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_text, null); 

addTab(newTab().setCustomView(customView));
```

---